# How do I set a HTTP GET query variable in \Illuminate\Http\Request?

Tags: laravel, http

I'd like to set a GET variable within the request within a middleware.

How can this be done?

I've had a look at the documentation at : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests but can't find anything relating to setting a GET variable.

Comment: What do you mean with 'setting' a GET variable? GET variables are set directly in query strings, and then captured as parameters in routes.php file... See Laravel routing docs.

Comment: A 'HTTP' request encapsulates headers, GET variables, POST variables. How do I set a GET variable?

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding you anyway, but if you would like to manually add a (GET or POST, it doesn't matter) variable to a request in one of your middleware, you can do it by simply assigning it: `$request -> foo = 'bar';`

Comment: It's not clear whether that sets a POST or a GET variable? Are they both combined perhaps?

Comment: Of course, GET and POST variables are indistinctly accessed within the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instances :)

Comment: Well great sounds like it isn't really supported then.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comments, Laravel's `Request` class does not support handling `GET` parameters independently.

The end.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred not to set GET variable in Laravel, the variables are managed using slashes (/) and routes, The (Request $request) variable is also only available in POST/PATCH etc. it will not be available in GET.
You can set the session variables in GET using

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

If you want to do that in the middleware; remember to add your middleware in the web middlewaregroup at the end. The reason to do that is if session middleware is not started you cannot start yours before that.